# How to make links behind a div with a superior z-index value clickable?

Tags: html, css

I have this design for an HTML book and i am trying to achieve a certain effect which fading the text when scrolling the page which i successfully done using a fixed div with a superior z-index value and a PNG background image.

```
.book-bg {
background: url(../../img/book-frame-bg.png) no-repeat fixed center top;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 100;}
```

But now all my links which covered by the ".book-bg" div aren't clickable, how can i solve this?

Sample page here: http://mmahgoub.com/thebook/chapter-01.html

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [Firefox, Opera and Chrome/Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility) you could use [`pointer-events: none`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) in your CSS rule.  If you need IE compatibility as well then try [Forwarding Mouse Events Through Layers](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/).

Comment: Strangely enough IE9 doesn't recognize pointer-events: none; what a shame!

Comment: @mmahgoub It's really supposed to be for SVG, I don't expect IE will support it in HTML till they've added support for it in SVG.

Answer (score 1):

your links will need a higher z-index, for this they will need to be positioned, relative, floated or fixed.