# Button with a png over it

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I have a simple div that acts as button. It has a hover action an it works fine.
However, I have a png on top of this button with z-index:2, covering half of it, and of course, the button hover doesn't work when I pass the mouse over the png.

I was wondering if there's a way in css to ignore this png, so the button will work even under it.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

Comment: If you set the `z-index` of the button to be higher when it is being hovered it should appear above the PNG. I don't believe you can hover over the element while the PNG is covering it.

Comment: Can't you add a hover for the png as well?

Answer (score 0):

[How to make links behind a div with a superior z-index value clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414188/how-to-make-links-behind-a-div-with-a-superior-z-index-value-clickable)

Tried a better use of keywords in google and found my answer in the link above.
All I needed was to use "pointer-events: none" in the png class.